# How can I put two divs next to each other in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to put two divs next to each other but no matter what I do, the second div always ends up somewhere under the first. I have tried:

```
div.one {
width:50%;
float:left;
}

div.two {
width:50%
float:right;
margin-left:50%;
}
```

and

```
div.one {
width:50%;
display:inline-block;
}

div.two {
width:50%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Percentage widths are not accurate when you're using borders. The border might be occupying some pixels.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it using elements from all the answers.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

From your first example try removing the margin.

```
div.one {
   width:50%;
   float:left;
}

div.two {
    width:50%
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if my edit is showing publicly yet, but here's a Fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/4KmsB/

Answer (score 1):

```
#div-1a {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
width:200px;
}
#div-1b {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:200px;
}
```

Here is a link to a great tutorial that gives you several examples of positioning: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning

Answer (score 0):

Both should be "float:left;"

The elements have to fit - when there is a border , margin or padding, the "width:50%;" might be too high.

Comment: If the parent div can't keep them both aligned, then if both have float left or not, it's the same, the problem isn't in the float, it's with the parent container OR borders...margins and such.

Answer (score 0):

```
.one {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
}

.two {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qf9GD/